# How did Fred Madison change into Pete Dayton in prison?

Tags: plot-explanation, lost-highway

How did Fred Madison change into Pete Dayton in prison in *Lost Highway*?

Comment: IMHO this is unanswerable. Lynch has never explained the movie, and most likely never will, so all you'll get is an endless list of interpretations, e.g. https://italkyoubored.wordpress.com/2013/01/30/david-lynchs-lost-highway-who-is-dick-laurent/ . The screenplay has been published as a book but doesn't offer any explanation either AFAIK: https://www.amazon.com/Lost-Highway-David-Lynch/dp/0571191509

Comment: I wondered this myself, but just assumed it was David Lynch being David Lynch.

Comment: I've always seen it as a dream (same narrative as Mulholland Dr.): he goes to jail and dreams he could start it all over again younger, but reality seeps through the dream. He's in jail dreaming the whole time. The mysterious man symbolizes a taunt: death or waking up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bill had a very bad headache and ask for medicine in prison. He was suspicious about his wife and killed her.

After being arrested by police he psycologically transformed to a young good guy with pure heart in prison.

The camera man is Bill's instinct. This man is under high pressure within murdering his wife and psychologically transformed.